# How to check if specific value exists in side an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following sample function.

```
class EquipmentReport extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Reporting/ReportModel');//load report model
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->Authorize(); // method inherited and returns array
 }

    /**
     * loads view if no $_POST data
     * if post data generates sql query
     * @return (query)
     **/


    public function by_category (){
         $my_array = $this->Authorize();
        if (in_array("USER_GROUP_STATUS", $my_array)) {
            echo "Got USER_GROUP_STATUS";
        }
}
```

dumping $my_array gives the following array

```
Array ( 
 [0] =>  'ALL',
         'USER_GROUP_STATUS',
         'USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_CREATE_DEPARTMENT',
         'USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_READ_DEPARTMENT',
         'USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_UPDATE_DEPART'
      )
```

but checking array keys is nt working.
what I wanted to do is to check if the one of the values exist. for example if `'USER_GROUP_STATUS'` exists in the array ?

Comment: `array_search("to serach", $array)`

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI ...its nt working that way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `in_array()` function

```
    if (in_array("USER_GROUP_STATUS", $your_array)) {
    echo "Got USER_GROUP_STATUS";
}
```

or You can try this way

```
    $ary = [
 0 =>  ['ALL', 'USER_GROUP_STATUS', 'USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_CREATE_DEPARTMENT',
         'USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_READ_DEPARTMENT',
         'USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_UPDATE_DEPART']
      ];

foreach($ary as $ar)
if (in_array("USER_GROUP_STATUS", $ar)) {
            echo "Got USER_GROUP_STATUS";
        }
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/WegPJ)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use in_array() :

```
if (in_array($string, $Arr)) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourArray = Array ( [0] => ALL,'USER_GROUP_STATUS','USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_CREATE_DEPARTMENT','USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_READ_DEPARTMENT','USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_UPDATE_DEPART' );

$needle = 'USER_GROUP_STATUS';

if(in_array($needle, $yourArray)) {
    echo 'found it!';
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i tried this bt i am nt getting anything     $needle = "USER_GROUP_STATUS";
        $my_array = $this->Authorize();
        if(in_array($needle,$my_array)) {
            echo 'found it!';
            die();
        }

Answer (score 0):

do sth like this

```
public function by_category()
    {

        $key= "USER_GROUP_STATUS";
        $my_array = $this->Authorize();
        if(in_array($key,$my_array)) {
            echo 'Bravo!';
            die();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not to mention you can use single quotes. like this $key= 'USER_GROUP_STATUS';